# SC16IS752: how to design it for higher bauds?

Tags: i2c, spi, uart

I am planning to use [this](https://www.nxp.com/products/peripherals-and-logic/signal-chain/bridges/dual-uart-with-ic-bus-spi-interface-64-bs-of-transmit-and-receive-fifos-irda-sir-built-in-support:SC16IS752_SC16IS762) IC for adding more UARTs to my PI.

It is stated that max baud rates are 5Mbps, which is perfect for my purposes.

However I2C's max bitrate can hardly reach these high numbers especially if my intention is to connect more of these ICs to PI.

Can you confirm that these high bauds are only available in case of SPI interface is being used?

Also I have found a design here: https://github.com/TD-er/SC16IS752.

Here the author states:

> The maximum transfer speed of SC16IS752 is 115,200bps.

I don't understand this limitation, but I can imagine this is due to low frequency XTAL?

How is the XTAL affects baudrate in case of these ICs?

Answer (score 3):

It can almost certainly reach up to its maximum baud rate over I2C, but you will have to have gaps in the transmission to transfer the data to/from of the chip using I2C. The chip contains a 64-byte transmit FIFO and a 64-byte receive FIFO, so it can transmit or receive up to 64 bytes before the I2C interface becomes a bottleneck. When transmitting, you can disable the transmitter while you fill the FIFO, so you can transmit up to 64 bytes at the baud rate instead of at I2C speed.

Comment: Yepp, thanks, but in general SPI is more capable for handling continuous, high bauds?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, as the datasheet says, I2C only goes up to 400kHz

Answer (score 2):

The baud rates up to 5 Mbps are available regardless of which interface you use. You need the baud rate clock from a crystal to be high enough to achieve 5 Mbps.

While the SC16IS752 can transfer data over UART at 5 Mbps, it only has a 4 MHz SPI interface and 400 kbps I2C interface, so you can never have 5 Mbps throughput.

If you connect multiple of these chips, they all need to share the 4 MHz SPI bus so with one UART you can have almost 4 Mbps but if two UARTs need to be used simultaneously then you have less bandwidth for one UART.

Comment: surely it would be easier and more performant to use USB->serial devices?

Comment: I dont actually need 5Mbps, but let's say 3Mbps. This is achievable via SPI and not via I2C, but how can I calculate the correct xtal value in case of this IC?

Comment: @Daniel How to calculate baud rate from crystal speed is explained in the datasheet. Have you read that part and if you have which part of it is unclear?

Comment: Oh sorry I might have missed it.